# Leaflet map color appear lighter

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to make a simple map with Leaflet in R Markdown. I used standard deviation classification method to divide the data into 4 classes. When it produces the map, the colors on the map appear much lighter than what they should be. What is the problem here ? Thank you!

````
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)
library(readr)
STCOU<- readOGR("H:/SP/STCOU.shp", "STCOU", GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE)
UNGEOCODED <- read_csv("H:/SP/UNGEOCODED.csv")

palette1 <- colorBin(c('#f1eef6','#bdc9e1','#74a9cf','#0570b0'),bins = c(0,1600, 3400, 5200, 32000),pretty = FALSE)

palette2 <- colorBin(c('#ece7f2','#a6bddb','#2b8cbe'),bins = c(0,1816, 3821, 35781),pretty = FALSE)

popup1<-paste("2015 Ungeocoded Tallies",
         "<br>GEO_ID: ",
         STCOU$GEOID,
         "<br>State: ",
         STCOU$STATEFP,
         "<br>County: ",
         STCOU$COUNTYFP,
         "<br>Name: ",
         STCOU$NAME,
         "<br>LSAD: ",
         STCOU$LSAD,
         "<br>CensusArea: ",
         STCOU$ALAND,
         "<br>Current_UNGEO_Counts: ",
         STCOU$CURRENT_UN,
         "<br>Fall15_UNGEO_Counts: ",
         STCOU$FAL15_UNGE)

popup2<-paste("2016 Ungeocoded Tallies",
         "<br>GEO_ID: ",
         STCOU$GEOID,
         "<br>State: ",
         STCOU$STATEFP,
         "<br>County: ",
         STCOU$COUNTYFP,
         "<br>Name: ",
         STCOU$NAME,
         "<br>LSAD: ",
         STCOU$LSAD,
         "<br>CensusArea: ",
         STCOU$ALAND,
         "<br>Current_UNGEO_Counts: ",
         STCOU$CURRENT_UN,
         "<br>Fall15_UNGEO_Counts: ",
         STCOU$FAL16_UNGE)
```

### Ungeocoded 2015 2016

```{r}
leaflet() %>%
setView(lng = -94.308561, lat = 38.561161, zoom=5) %>%
addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas",
               options = tileOptions()) %>%
addPolygons(data=STCOU,weight=0.1,
          fillColor = ~palette1(UNGEOCODED$FAL15_UNGE),
          popup = popup1,
          group="<span style='color: #7f0000; font-size: 11pt'><strong>2015</strong></span>")%>%
addPolygons(data=STCOU,weight=0.1,
          fillColor = ~palette2(UNGEOCODED$SPR16_UNGE),
          popup=popup2,
          group="2016") %>%
addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("<span style='color: #7f0000; font-size: 11pt'><strong>2015</strong></span>",
               "2016"), options = layersControlOptions(collapsed =FALSE))%>%
addLegend(position = 'topleft',
       colors = c('#f1eef6','#bdc9e1','#74a9cf','#0570b0'), 
       labels = c('Low'," "," ","High"),
       opacity = 0.6,
       title = "2015 2016 Ungeocoded")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to read the docs on the various `addLayers` functions in leaflet package and you'll see that `fillOpacity` is set to 0.2 as the default. This is to save you from yourself when features overlap, but you can definitely set the parameter higher, i.e.

Minimal Reproducible Example + Answer -->

```
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
  lon = sample(seq(-94.9, -93.1, 0.00001), 10, replace = T),
  lat = sample(seq(38.1, 39.9, 0.00001), 10, replace = T),
  value = sample(density(c(0,1600, 3400, 5200, 32000))$x, 10)
) 

palette1 <- colorBin(c('#f1eef6','#bdc9e1','#74a9cf','#0570b0'), bins = c(0,1600, 3400, 5200, 32000), pretty = FALSE)

leaflet(df) %>%
  setView(lng = -94.308561, lat = 38.561161, zoom=7) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(
    weight=0.1, 
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    fillColor = ~palette1(value)
  )
```